# Is it possible to hide the iOS browser chrome on a website and link to an external site?

Tags: ios5, browser, hide, iphone-standalone-web-app

Is it possible to build a website that is hiding the browser chrome on iOS5 while still linking to external websites? The browser chrome should not be shown when the external site his opened.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible when the website is added to the home screen and contains this meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

You can't hide the chrome from the Safari app itself.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am doing. The problem is when I link to a different URI it's being opened in the mobile safari with chrome. Do I need to build a one page app?

Answer (score 0):

I found this works,

$('body').delay('1000').animate({ scrollTop: '0px' }, 'slow');

I noticed that scrolling down removed it, so scrolled 60px (height of the chrome), but that hide it and scrolled down the page, but a scroll of 0px, assuming your page has started at the top no on a # target, fools it!

I guess you could even remove the delay and animate, but I wanted it to be smooth, and not too jerky.